# Deploy .net mvc app with front end on knockout js to docker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core, containers, signalr

I have a .net mvc app built on .net framework 4.6.2. It uses signalR and knockout.js for all front end functionalities.

I need to deploy the app on docker what are the possible ways to achieve this? Should I convert the app to .net core? I might have to write several pieces again as .net mvc and .net core doesn't share common signalR library.

Is there a way to containerize the app without having to do much changes in the app itself?

Comment: .NET Framework is Windows only, so if you want to containerize it as-is, you must run it on a Windows Docker host. If you want to run it on a Linux Docker host, you have to move it to .NET core or .NET 5+.

Comment: Yes @HansKilian, But Is there a possibility to convert the app to .net core without changing the front end that is on knockout? 
P.S Its not a separate project the knockout code is embedded in mvc views.